# How to solve error C2334 when include boost library in Visual studio 15?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, include

I have, unziped boost, executeted, boostrap.bat, b2.exe, and in visual studio project properties, in C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories, the root of boost folder, and in Linker>General>Aditional Library Directories, "boost root"/stage/lib".

But when I use `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` I get the following error:

[image]

[image]
How to solve this?

Comment: What is the error message? What is the code? I can't read the screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution,

if you change the `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` to the begining of the file the problem is solved.